# How to have ellipsis, clamp lines, and have text after ellipsis?

Tags: javascript, html, css

To display movie titles, I would like to have ellipsis, clamp the total number of lines to two, and have the year of the movie behind the ellipsis, such that a movie title like

```
Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind (2004)
```

would be displayed like

```
Eternal Sunshine of
the Spotl... (2004)
```

when the width is restricted.

This would be straight-forward if it were *one* line, but I want *two*.

I have looked around on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find any way to achieve all three of these. I would prefer a pure CSS solution, as using JavaScript for this seems finicky, but if that's not possible I guess I don't really have a choice.

Comment: I *think* it's possible with CSS **if** you put the year in its own element (such as a `span`). Is that feasible in your case? (Or you may need to put both the title and the year in separate `span`s or similar.) But I could also be mistaken, the two lines part of this makes it especially tricky. (But modern CSS is really powerful.)

Comment: I do not think you can have the ellipsis _and_ the wrapping text in CSS since the ellipsis relies on preventing the line-breaks.

Comment: @Temani - Oh, wow, nice find! So if/when `line-clamp` is added, it would be `line-clamp: 2 attr(data-year);` with the year in a `data-year` attribute?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not sure about the attr() part as this one is only support with content but in the future it should also work with other properties so it would be good to have it with clamp as well

Comment: So I guess its not really possible then, yet. The question this question is now associated with only has answers with barely working, hacky solutions.